# Batch File Loops with delims

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am getting only 1 item: **Adding - RegistrationPool** for the following for loop below. What have I done wrong? How do I iterate to the next token/item?

```
for /F "delims=!" %%i in ("RegistrationPool"!"SubSystemService") DO (
    echo Adding - %%i
    echo.

)
```

Comment: the `(` needs to be on the same line as the `DO`

Comment: Thanks ! that help, but now I got a new problem. the loop only iterate once

Comment: what exactly do you try to do?

Comment: updated my question above. it is not printing Adding - SubSystemService

Comment: The `!` isn't in the string, so there's no `!` delimiter to split by.

Comment: I tried ("RegistrationPool!SubSystemService"). It only prints RegistrationPool only

Comment: `SubSystemService` is the 2nd token, but the `for /f` takes only the first unless you add `"tokens=1,2`.  I think you mean something like `for %%i in (alpha,beta) do echo %%i` but this doesn't work with an exclamation mark as delimiter. Adding `delims=!` requires the `/f`switch, but that changes the way it works. Do you have the chance to replace `!` with a space or a comma?

Comment: I can use comma. Does that mean that I will not have to use delims with comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use  a comma or a space instead of an exclamation mark, you can simply use:

```
for %%i in (RegistrationPool,SubSystemService) DO (
    echo testing %%i
    echo.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To split a string you need a string to split

```
for /F "delims=!" %%i in ("RegistrationPool!SubSystemService") DO (
    echo Adding - %%i
)
```

But this will still only print one "Adding" line. Why?. `for /f` will iterate over the files/lines, executing the content of the `do` body **once** per line. You have only one line (with two tokens, but one line) so only one iteration.

You can access the second element as a second token

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=!" %%i in ("RegistrationPool!SubSystemService") DO (
    echo Adding - %%i
    echo Adding - %%j
)
```

First token is stored in the indicated replaceable parameter, and the following tokens in alphabetical order.

But, if iterating over a list is what is needed, then the correct construct is

```
for %%i in ("RegistrationPool" "SubSystemService") DO (
    echo Adding - %%i
)
```

Now, there is a `for` command iterating over a list of elements. Two elements, two iterations, two "Adding" lines.